# How do you remove dust between keyboard keys?

Tags: cleaning, dust

Is there any way how I can remove the dirty stuff between my keyboard without having to buy particular stuff to do it?

My laptop fell and now it is dirty, and I don't want to go to a shop to buy stuff.

Comment: This is a duplication of [How to clean crevices of electronics without compressed air?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/how-to-clean-crevices-of-electronics-without-compressed-air)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes run a vacuum hose over my keyboard (with the computer off) and simultaneously work the keys to give the dirt a path out.  For an even easier way, turn it upside down and shake/press keys while gravity does the work for you.  It gets most of the big stuff.

Comment: In addition to this great tip (watch out that you don't suck the keys right off the keyboard-it can happen), AVOID using compressed air which can ram particles **into** tight places *securely*. Thin plastic "scissor" springs under key caps are great for catching dust, fur, and hair. If that happens, you won't get that stuff out easily in the future.